# How can I filter data object by state array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ANSWERED - I have updated the code below to show the working example.

I'm currently building a portfolio in React with a Filter system. For example, a user will go to the portfolio page and select the filters (web design, development, etc.) they would like to see the projects for.

I have created a new array called updatedProjects, which should includes the projects filtered from ProjectData. I have provided an example below, where I require updatedProjects to contain any projects that have either of the tags "Brand Identity" or "Web Design"...

ProjectData.tsx

```
const ProjectData = [
  {
    title: "Project 1",
    tags: [
      { title: "Web Development", value: "web-development" },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "Project 2",
    tags: [
      { title: "Brand Identity", value: "brand-identity" },
      { title: "Brand Messaging", value: "brand-messaging" },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "Project 3",
    tags: [
      { title: "Brand Identity", value: "brand-identity" },
      { title: "Brand Guidelines", value: "brand-guidelines" },
      { title: "Brand Messaging", value: "brand-messaging" },
      { title: "Web Design", value: "web-design" },
    ],
  },
];
```

Projects.tsx

```
const filterProjects = (title) => {

// if filter is not already in array, add it. Else, remove it.
let updatedFilters = [];

if (!selectedFilters.includes(title)) {
  updatedFilters = [...selectedFilters, title];
} 
else {
  const updatedTags = selectedFilters.filter((el) => el !== title);
  updatedFilters = updatedTags;
}

setSelectedFilters(updatedFilters);


let updatedProjects = []; 

// Here I need to filter ProjectData using the selectedFilters state array. 
// This currently just filters by the most recent filter 'title', and not by 
// ALL titles in the selectedFilters array.

updatedProjects = ProjectData.filter((project) =>
  project.tags.some((tag) => updatedFilters.includes(tag.title))
);

setFilteredProjects(updatedProjects);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I had a look at your old code. You can follow something like this below to achieve the desired result.

```
const filterProjects = (title) => {

// if filter is not already in array, add it. Else, remove it.
let updatedFilters = [];

if (!selectedFilters.includes(title)) {
  updatedFilters = [...selectedFilters, title];
} 
else {
  const updatedTags = selectedFilters.filter((el) => el !== title);
  updatedFilters = updatedTags;
}

setSelectedFilters(updatedFilters);


let updatedProjects = []; 

// Here I need to filter ProjectData using the selectedFilters state array. 
// This currently just filters by the most recent filter 'title', and not by 
// ALL titles in the selectedFilters array.

updatedProjects = ProjectData.filter((project) =>
  project.tags.some((tag) => updatedFilters.includes(tag.title))
);

setFilteredProjects(updatedProjects);
};
```